# Play video from local directory ExoPlayer

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I would like to play a video stored in local storage `LocalContext.current.filesDir` but I keep on getting the PlayBack Error `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error`.

Here is how I'm trying to play the video:

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun VideoView(videoUri: String) {
        val context = LocalContext.current
    
        val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .build()
            .also { exoPlayer ->
                val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
                    .setUri(videoUri)
                    .build()
                exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
                exoPlayer.prepare()
            }
    
        DisposableEffect(
            AndroidView(factory = {
                StyledPlayerView(context).apply {
                    player = exoPlayer
                }
            })
        ) {
            onDispose { exoPlayer.release() }
        }
    }
```

Where `videoUri = LocalContext.current.filesDir/file.mp4`

Any solution to the problem? Thank you for reading.